# Aggregated AMI metrics return "INSUFFICIENT_DATA"

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, autoscaling, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to set up my own autoscaling system on AWS and I've set up alarms for any instance spawned with a specific AMI ID.

When I check the the metrics which are only monitoring one server, they get information just fine. The "aggregated" stats however always fail.

Is this a problem with AWS or does this not do what I think it does. I'll also point out these are all default metrics, not added through the CLI API.

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: The issue is not with my code, these are using default metrics through the AWS Console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled detailed monitoring for your instances? AWS supports aggregated metrics only for instances with detailed monitoring enabled:

> For the instances where you've enabled detailed monitoring, you can also get aggregated data across groups of similar instances.

See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_GetStatistics.html.

Answer (score 0):

If your cloud metrics says "insufficient data" that means your server have not met the state which you have configured using CLI.

Comment: I have not configured anything, these are default metrics provided by amazon, as noted in my question

Comment: That means your instance have not met the metrics defined by AWS itself.

Comment: So my instance does not have a CPU reading? No information about the memory and can't even count how many instances there are?